# Measured voltage and current different from the calculated value

Tags: voltage, led, current, multimeter

I am learning a simple LED and resistor circuit. I have the following components:

- One 5mm blue LED
- 5V USB power source

From what I've learned so far, I am using the following forward voltage 3V and 20mA of the blue LED. Therefore, the R = (5-3)/0.02 = 100ohm. I think this is the correct calculation. I am also able to put them all together and light up the LED without issue.

However when I use the multimeter to verify my calculation, both current and the voltage reading are completely different from my calculation. From the multimeter reading, here is the schematic and the measurements.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fklGjI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can someone point me out what have I done wrong and point me to the right way?

Comment: that is not the circuit that you used ... please verify the LED orientation

Comment: @jsotola yes either the battery or the LED must be flipped.

Comment: Did you get the forward voltage specification of 3V at 20ma from a datasheet? If so did it quote a typical and maximum forward voltage. There is usually a range in production tolerance due to manufacturing process variations. You might get a slightly different result with another Blue LED from a different batch. Obviously reality trumps simulation every time!

Comment: Sorry for the wrong orientations. Just fix them. Still have a lot to learn

Comment: Did you measure resistance of resistor?

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is pretty simple. The forward voltage estimate you used for the LED is wrong. Instead of being 3V at 20 mA, it is 3.57V at 14mA. You will get pretty close to what you want if you just re-calculate using 3.6V instead of 3V.

So, using your equation but with the modified forward voltage we have:

R = (5-3.6)/0.02 = 70 Ohms.

Standard values that might work are 75 Ohms, or 71.5 Ohms or 69.8 Ohms. If you run it at 20mA, make sure it will not burn out. Often 20mA is the max current for an LED, and is much brighter than necessary. Using 150 Ohms at 14mA might be better in practice.

Comment: It turns out that particular LED is completely different from the other blue LED from the same batch. I test with couple other LED from the same batch and all measurements come out the same as my calculatio. THANK YOU everyone's tips and help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer.

Please follow convention when drawing your schematic.

Vcc at top, ground at bottom, input on left, output on right.
(you can reverse the input/output if your language uses right to left writing)

It makes it easier to visualize the voltage levels in the circuit and makes it more difficult to make errors such as an LED being backwards as in your circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAwX83.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.